# Extending rebus with new transport

Tags: rebus

Has anyone tried implementing a new transport for Rebus? How much work is involved? E.g. number of interfaces that needs to be implemented? Assuming a sensible transport mechanism is used such as Greg Youngs event store..

Thank you.

Comment: **avoid asking subjective questions where** … you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”  Source: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: there is just one interface - IDuplexTransport. How much it takes to implement it, depends on transport itself I guess. mookid8000 says it's a lot of work though and I belive him :) Why not lurke into existing transports and see for youself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the aptly named @user1121956 says, it's a matter of implementing [`IDuplexTransport`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/IDuplexTransport.cs), which is just bringing [`ISendMessages`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/ISendMessages.cs) and [`IReceiveMessages`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/IReceiveMessages.cs) together.

As you can see, the two interfaces boil down to two methods, so when I say that it's a lot of work to implement a new transport, it's because it's not trivial to implement those methods.

It doesn't mean that it's not possible, it's just that it's a place where you would need to be very careful to get things right - otherwise, messages might be dropped or other bad things might happen, and that would not be cool :)

With that said - if you feel like you're up to it ;) -  I suggest you check out the Rebus source code and look into [the contract tests for the transports](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/tree/master/src/Rebus.Tests/Contracts/Transports) - this is where a bunch of common scenarios get run against all the officially supported transports. A good starting point would be to extend the tests with a `GregsEventStoreTransportFactory`.

I will be happy to help you out with guidance along the way if you run into trouble!

Comment: Thats great thx. Event store is going to be a central part of our organisations pub sub infrastructure and I believe rebus could provide a great programming model.

Comment: you send a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/)? :)

Comment: When I'm a bit more comfortable with the solution I'll do that :)

Comment: you could open a pull request anyways, and then I'll review the code and just wait with the merge until we're both comfortable?